# How to synchronize send and recv calls in socket programming in C?

Tags: c, sockets, send, recv

I want to send complete folder from the client to the server. The folder has binary files. But for now I m working with text files present in folder. Since I m going step by step, I m currently working on something like just displaying the name of files present in folder :

1. Opening directory
2. Reading whole directory
3. Sending name of the file one after another from the client to the server
4. Server is receiving it
5. After the whole folder has completed reading all files from it, the folder is closed.

The problem I m facing here is :
While sending the file name, the server receives the file names correctly but while the server is busy taking out stuff from buffer, the client already writes to the buffer the next file names and hence two or more file names get appended to the buffer and the server reads it all at once.

How do I go about this problem as I want the client to send just one file name at one time and the server should receive just that one file name. How should I synchronize these calls? Or How should I restrict the buffer?

Server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define MAX 1024
#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/foo"

int s, s2, t, len;
struct sockaddr_un local, remote;

void createSSocket()
{
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nServer Socket Created...");
}

void setSSocketPath()
{
    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    printf("\nServer Socket Path Set...");
}

void bindSocket()
{
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) 
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSocket Binded...");
}

void listenSocket()
{   
    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) 
    {
          perror("listen");
          exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nListening Socket...");
}

void acceptConnection()
{
    printf("\nWaiting for a connection...");
    t = sizeof(remote);
    if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nServer Socket Connected...");
}

void closeSSocket()
{
    close(s2);
    printf("\nServer Socket Closed...");
}

void receiveData()
{
    char str[MAX] = {0};
    int n;
    while(1)
    {
        //printf("\n%d ... %s",n,str);
        n = recv(s2, str, MAX, 0);
        str[n] = 0;
        printf("\n%d ... %s",n,str);
        if(!strcmp(str,"@#$%")) // 2345
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    createSSocket();    
    setSSocketPath();
    bindSocket();
    listenSocket();
    acceptConnection();

    receiveData();

    closeSSocket();
    return 0;   
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define MAX 1024
#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/foo"


int s, t, len;
struct sockaddr_un remote;
char path[MAX] = "/home/priyanka/criu-1.4/3455";  //to retieve path from folder
DIR *dirDes;
struct dirent *expFile;

void createCSocket()
{
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nClient Socket Created...");
}

void setCSocketPath()
{
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    printf("\nClient Socket Path Set...");
}

void connectSocket()
{
    printf("\nTrying to connect...");
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) 
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nClient Connected...\n");
}

void closeCSocket()
{
    close(s);
    printf("\nClient Socket Closed...");
}

void readDirectory()
{
    char temp[MAX] = {0};
    dirDes = opendir(path);     //open the directory in which files related to process are dumped
    if(dirDes == NULL)
        printf("Error Opening Directory !!! \n");
   else
   {
        while(expFile = readdir(dirDes))    //read the directory
        {
            int bb;
            char str[MAX] = {0};
            if(strcmp(expFile -> d_name,".") == 0)      //skip folder with name "."
                continue;
            if(strcmp(expFile -> d_name,"..") == 0)     //skip folder with name ".."
                continue;
            strcpy(temp,path);
            if(temp[strlen(temp)-1]!='/')       //if the temp has / appended at the end skip else append
            strcat(temp,"/");
            strcat(temp,expFile->d_name);       //append the file name read to the path
            printf("\n%s",temp);
            sprintf(str,"%d",strlen(temp));
            bb = send(s,str,strlen(str),0);
            if(bb == -1)
            {
                perror("Error sending file name length");
            }
            bb = send(s,temp,strlen(temp),0);
            //sleep(1);
            if(bb == -1)
            {
                perror("Error sending file name");
            }
            /*else
            {
                printf("Name sent 1\n");
            }*/
        }   
        closedir(dirDes);       //close directory
        send(s,"@#$%",strlen("@#$%"),0);
    }
}


int main()
{
    createCSocket();
    setCSocketPath();
    connectSocket();

    readDirectory();    

    closeCSocket(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's two common ways, either to prepend the length of the data, or to have a terminator or separator. Or some way of saying "this data is a file-name" and "this data is file contents".

Comment: You can implement an HTTP-like protocol, where the client (receiver) actively has to request the next entry before the server (sender) sends it. However, if you know that the receiver wants a listing of the whole directory, it's bad for network utilization, so @JoachimPileborg's suggestion will be more efficient (and probably easier to implement).

Comment: This is not synchronization problem, this is communication protocol problem. Design the stream structure which can be parsed by another side. For example, 0 byte after every file name, and two consecutive 0 bytes in the end of the list.

Comment: Also check what `recv()` returns.

Comment: I had thought about parsing stuff on the other side, but the problem here is that if the file itself contains that string used as terminator then it will be a problem.

Comment: I heard about blocking send till receive call clears the buffer by sending acknowledgement on the other side. Will this help me out?

Comment: That's how TCP already works. It won't help you any more than it already does. Unclear what you're asking.